# How to indicate which model's field raised a ValidationError?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have a simple Django model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):    
    description = models.CharField('description', max_length=150,
                                   validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, 'Description\'s min length is 2'), ])
    amount = models.DecimalField('amount', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, 
                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(1, 'Min value is 1'), ])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    # to trigger model fields' validation
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Transaction, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And I'd like to have a unit test, which precisely checks whether `ValidationError` is raised by *description* field and not by *amount* field (or any other).

So I have this piece of test, which in a primitive way checks if *description* field is present in `e.exception`:

```
def test_model_requires_description_min_2_characters(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as e:
        Transaction.objects.create(description='a', amount="50", user=self.user1)
    err_dict = eval(str(e.exception))
    self.assertIn('description', err_dict.keys())
```

But I don't really like to use `eval()` and I believe there is more elegant way to indicate the source of `ValidationError`. How can I do this?

EDIT: my model class also includes overriden `clean()` and `save()` methods, so validators are running fine.

Comment: An `.objects.create(...)` bypasses the validation process, it will *never* generate a `ValidationError` anyway.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes, you're right. I didn't mentioned it, but I have clean() and save() methods overriden, so validators are executing correctly. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this, `ValidationError` has an attribute `error_dict` that we can already use to test for this

```
def test_model_requires_description_min_2_characters(self):
    try:
        Transaction.objects.create(description='a', amount="50", user=self.user1)
    except ValidationError as e:
        # A ValidationError was raised, now we test to see if our field is in it
        self.assertIn('description', e.error_dict.keys())
    else:
        # No exception was raised, raise our own exception
        raise Exception('The test failed')
```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - actually @Iain Shelvington is right. In `try ... except ValidationError as e` we have an access to `e.error_dict`. When using `with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as e` (as I did in my code) error_dict is not available

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in this instance it would. Field errors from cleaning models are passed to ValidationError as a dict and then assigned to error_dict here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/exceptions.py#L115

Comment: @IainShelvington: no, that is conditional, given a dictionary is passed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and in this instance a dictionary is being passed because mchfrnc is calling full_clean, which calls clean_fields which passes a dictionary to ValidationError when there are errors

Comment: @IainShelvington: yeah, but as a functional programmer, I really do not like the *non-totalness* of this :). Especially since it is not a reusable exception pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not all `ValidationError` objects *have* an `error_dict`. We can derive that from the [implementation of the constructor of the `ValidationError` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/core/exceptions.py#L96). It depends on whether the `message` (the first parameter of the construct) is a dictionary.

What we *can* do however is use [**`getattr(..)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) for this, with a fallback value, like:

```
def test_model_requires_description_min_2_characters(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as e:
        Transaction.objects.create(description='a', amount="50", user=self.user1)
    self.assertIn('description', getattr(e.exception, 'err_dict', {}))
```

So given the `error_dict` does not exists, we will let `getattr(..)` return an empty dictionary, and hence the `assertIn` fails.

We can also implement a utility function for this, like:

```
_singleton = object()

class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    def assertKeyInErrorDict(self, key, error):
        error_dict = getattr(error, 'err_dict', _singleton)
        if error_dict is _singleton:
            self.fail('The error {} has no error_dict'.format(error))
        else:
            self.assertIn(key, error_dict)

    def test_model_requires_description_min_2_characters(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as e:
            Transaction.objects.create(description='a', amount="50", user=self.user1)
        self.assertKeyInErrorDict('description', e.exception)
```

You can thus ass such `assertKeyInErrorDict` in a utility class that provides extra assert functions, and then use it in all subclasses, removing a lot of *boilerplate* code.